# Testing of neural network in pattern recognition

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, neural-network

I've implemented a neural network for the pattern recognition. 
From the two classes of images I've used SIFT feature + BOvW to make the image descriptor.
After training and validation I've got confusion matrix with accuracy 80% overall.
here I am having two doubts
(I've done it in MATLAB GUI)

1)when ever I am training the network it gives different values (confusion matrix) in that case how can I validate the network? (MATLAB documentation says its due to different initial conditions how can I set one then?, I am not changing division of images)

2) how can I use this network to tell the category of the image if I input one, after training and validation

Comment: when you say, 'it gives different values', how different are they? As a side note, can you not use SVM instead of neural networks? NNs seem to have problems when presented with few data samples.

Comment: Different values like when ever I've finished training+validation (MATLAB) confusion matrix gives overall accuracy in the range 50%-80%(several times). But mostly more than 70%. Is there any thing seriously wrong in that?, In MATLAB GUI also it is written like  "Training multiple times will generate different results due to different initial conditions and sampling"  Is there any way to fix it for the good result?. I've 70 samples for each class will it be a reason for that? (SVM is good option but my objective is to use neural network and analysis its performance in object detection)

Comment: Yes that's bad.. What kind of neural network are you using? Single layer, multi layer? How about this - Use an SVM and look at the confusion matrix and accuracy. If you really can't get a reasonable level of accuracy, I guess you could reason that something is wrong with the feature.

Comment: I've used single hidden layer consisting of 200,300 hidden neurons results is not getting better for hidden layer increments. I've used both Training function Levenberg-Marquardt back propagation and Scaled conjugate gradient back propagation still no improvement. Ill check whatever you suggested (svm) and post it. Thank you!